# Material and rendering preview

Tags: materials

how can I view in the rendering (and therefore also in the preview of the rendering) the background image that I see in the material preview? [image: material preview]

Comment: Go to your World Shader (click on shading tab, change dropdown box in middle-left that says "object" to world), add an Environment Texture > click the folder > navigate your pc to your blender folder at .../3.4/datafiles/studiolights/world and choose "forest.exr" as the image.

Comment: thank you for your answer..! I already knew this procedure....
this image as a background is too focused and detailed, in the sense that my subject (compared to the background) comes out totally out of context, the trees are too big compared to the castle
I've never been able to find the right balance between the effect you get in the material preview and the rendering effect...can you blur the background image in the render?

Comment: I don't think you can blur an HDRI for a render (or even in composite, as far as I know). Maybe take the image file and blur it in something like photoshop or gimp.

Comment: For blurring the background I have written an answer - for the size of the trees compared to the scene there is the problem that an environment HDRI usually is a 360° view so it encloses the complete scene. If the trees were too close when the HDRI image was taken, you get the problem that scaling it down results in the background getting repeated. You might be able to hide that from view, but if you are using the HDRI for lighting the scene this can give unwanted effects...

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Blurring an HDRI in the world shader is no big problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can blur the background by using a *Texture Coordinate* node. By default, the background's *Environment Texture* uses the *Generated* coordinates. If you take a *Mix Color* node set to *Linear Light* you can add a *Noise Texture* to blur the HDRI.

The *Scale* setting of the *Noise Texture* determines how grainy the blur effect is (higher value = smoother blur), the *Factor* in the *Mix Color* node determines how strong the blur effect is. The *Detail* and *Roughness* values of the noise have an effect, too (I leave the detail at default and set the *Roughness* to 1 but that's not mandatory).

To avoid noisy and bad lighting in the scene, I only use the blurred background for the camera and therefore I mix it with an unaltered sharp version of the HDRI by *Light Path* > *Is Camera Ray*. You can do this by mxing the vectors for the texture.

Setup:

[image: world shader setup]

Comparison between different noise scales:

[image: noise scales]

Comparison between different mix factors:

[image: mix factors]