# Glass reflection not connected to environment

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I’m trying to replicate the reflection effect given by blender’s default ext image (specifically studio.exr) strength 1600 world opacity 1000 and blur 0.50, where the background is blurred but reflections on the object are clear, giving also different type of shadows to objects. I’ve tried blurring the original exr in photoshop and using it as an environment texture but then realized reflections are from the blurred exr which is not what I wanted. Is there any way around to disconnect reflections to object so that I could have the 2 exr separated, 1 as the background (the blurred) and the other one (the clear) as the reflective ?

Comment: You can use the setup in my answer here: [Material and rendering preview](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285596/material-and-rendering-preview/285648#285648) to blur the background for the camera and not the reflections. The good thing here is, you can switch the HDRI to your liking without the need to prepare a blurred one beforehand. This way you also only need to provide the memory space for one image... and you can change the blurriness if you want more or less. But I have to admit that the answer given here renders faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually figured it out by using uv reflection > base color in the object shader

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Is Glossy Ray* output of an *Input > Light Path* node as factor in a *Mix Shader* that mixes your 2 HDRI images:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually figured it out by using uv reflection > base color in the object shader